# hide legend for some series in flot

Tags: hide, flot, legend

Hi I have a flot chart with series like this:

- foo
- bar
- foo/second
- bar/second

The relative values (per second) are displayed as lines, whereas the absolute values are displayed as columns. All within the same chart. Absolute and relative of the same entity have the same color. I want the legend to be like this:

- [red] foo
- [blue] bar

I achieved this by setting the label of the relative series to null. However, I use the label when hovering over a point in the series. Now the null value is futile.

So is there a way to explicitly hide a series in the legend, but still set its label?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the label of the data series itself to null, use a `labelFormatter` function for your legend (see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend)):

```
labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
    // series is the series object for the label
    // label is the original label

    if (showInLegend) {
        return label;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Raidri's answer would have worked for me if my environment had a newer version of flot. Unfortunately since we're on flot 0.6 I had to go into the flot.js file and move a couple of lines of code in the insertLegend function around so that a null return from labelFormatter would actually skip the label instead of literally labeling the legend entry 'null' on my plot.
Thanks for a clear answer Raidri! Note: I don't have enough reputation to comment on his answer so I had to leave another answer and reference his instead. Hope this is helpful if anyone else is stuck on an older version of flot.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily hide the entire legend using:

```
    $('.legend').hide();
```

If you inspect the legend DOM object, you'll see it's a table of rows. You can hide any of the rows accordingly.